# Track affiliate conversions with GA or FB Pixel

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, affiliate, facebook-pixel

I have a wordpress voucher code website and working with most important affiliate platforms (Traetracker, Tradedoubles, Webgains, Beelbon, Awin).

I would like to track in real time when a commision is generated with GA and FB Pixel and im not able to do this.

Could anyone give me any clue?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can set up facbook pixel tracking using this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/facebook-conversion-pixel/)

I've used it in the past to track FB pixel. As for GA, there are multiple plugins to do this.

We (the company i work for) used Monster Insights from Yoast. [Monster Insights](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-analytics-for-wordpress/)

There isn't much point reinventing the wheel and both work well. The only issue i ever encountered was with the FB Pixel. There was a jQuery conflict. AFAIK it has been fixed since.

Answer (score 0):

@bogski87 thanks for the answer but think that plugins dont configure the affiliate callback.

I Know that, for example, in webgains you can configure a callback page where by post or get the platform sends transaction data in real time. I think this is the way but dont know how to configure that callbacks correctly.